# Optimal way to capture error while creating record in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have below code which insert record in `job_titles` table which is working perfectly fine. I have used double check in that code in case of failures(Try/Catch and If Statement). I needed to know is it really required or only one method can suffice. If only one method is sufficient then which one i should use.

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {

        try {
            $rules = [
                'code' => 'required | max:4 | unique:job_titles,code',
                'title' => 'required',
                'description' => 'required'
            ];

            $validated = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);


            if ($validated->fails()) {
                return response()->json(['status' => 'error', 'message' => 'Please correct validation errors', 'errors' => $validated->errors()]);
            }

            $newJobTitle = JobTitle::create([
                'title' => $request->get('title'),
                'code' => strtoupper($request->get('code')),
                'description' => $request->get('description')
            ]);
            if (!$newJobTitle) {
                return response()->json(['status' => 'error', 'message' => 'Something went wrong!!']);
            }

            return response()->json([
                'status' => 'success',
                'message' => 'Job Title ' . $request->get('title') . ' created successfully'
            ]);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return response()->json(['status' => 'error', 'message' => 'Something went wrong!!', 'exception_message' => $e]);
        }

    }
```

I have confusion Between these:

```
try{
}catch(Exception e)
{
}
```

**OR**

```
 $newJobTitle = JobTitle::create([
                'title' => $request->get('title'),
                'code' => strtoupper($request->get('code')),
                'description' => $request->get('description')
            ]);
            if (!$newJobTitle) {
                return response()->json(['status' => 'error', 'message' => 'Something went wrong!!']);
            }
```

**OR**

`Both the above option`

Comment: The laravel validator already throws an appropriate exception with the errors that occured and is send as a JSON response if the request accepts JSON. There's no need for a try-catch for that part. And also you **must** return an error response code when sending an error response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`try/catch` is going to give you more granular control over how to react to specific exceptions being thrown. However, comparing truthy values doesn't execute an `Exception` so as you can see you end up having a redundancy in your need to report errors. Instead of returning the response when there is no `$newJobTitle`, you can just throw an exception here:

```
if (! $newJobTitle) {
    throw new Exception('Job title does not exist');
}
```

Now when you return your message you can use `$e->getMessage()`

```
return response()->json(['status' => 'error', 'message' => $e->getMessage()]);
```

However, you could have your own custom exception, say for instance, `JobTitleMissingException`:

Now you can throw `JobTitleMissingException` and capture that exception specifically, so you can return a different error code, for instance:

```
catch(JobTitleMissingException $e) {
    return response()->json(['status' => 'error-job-title', 'message' => $e->getMessage()]);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    return response()->json(['status' => 'error', 'message' => $e->getMessage()]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, it's a good practice to use try/catch block when working with database so you can handle exceptions such as :

- integrity constraint violation
- unique constraint
- ...

and return a good response that the end user can understand such as **email already exists** instead of **Something went wrong**.

let's take an example for a registration scenario :

if you have a User table and it's structure looks like this:
id(AI), email(UNIQUE), password

user1 try to register with email user1@gmail.com and everything is OK, but when another user try to register with the same email, your query will end up with a unique constraint violation for email column and with try/catch you know exactly what happened out there.

so if you use the second approach:

```
    if (!$newJobTitle) {
        return response()->json(['status' => 'error', 'message' => 'Something went wrong!!']);
    }
```

you can't tell what happened.

Hint: you don't need to wrap all your code inside try/catch.

this should be enough :

```
try{
$newJobTitle = JobTitle::create([
                'title' => $request->get('title'),
                'code' => strtoupper($request->get('code')),
                'description' => $request->get('description')
            ]);
}catch(\Exception $e) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would do:

```
$rules = [
   'code' => 'required | max:4 | unique:job_titles,code',
   'title' => 'required',
   'description' => 'required'
];
$this->validate($request, $rules);
$newJobTitle = JobTitle::create([
       'title' => $request->get('title'),
      'code' => strtoupper($request->get('code')),
      'description' => $request->get('description')
]);
return response()->json([
        'status' => 'success',
        'message' => 'Job Title ' . $request->get('title') . ' created successfully'
]);
```

And that is it. The framework will throw a validation exception if validation fails which gets converted to either a redirect response with errors passed to the view or to a JSON error response if the request was done via AJAX.

This should be enough. Notice that I don't wrap the whole thing in a try catch. Only wrap the parts and catch the exceptions **you can handle** in a try catch. Catching everything just to return a generic "oops" message is pointless and messy since you can achieve the same with a general exception handler method and/or shutdown function, which Laravel also has so again you don't need to do anything except customise your errors.500 view.